# Azure AD B2C in Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I have some trouble integrating Azure AD B2C in my Xamarin Forms app. I have followed this guide https://dev.to/425show/user-authentication-in-xamarin-with-azure-ad-b2c-4clm.

The problem is, that after succesfull login the page only returns to the signin-button page (LoginPage.xaml).

Through breakpoints I can see that:

1: This part ends in the catch block but I cannot figure out why.

```
        {
            AuthenticationResult result;

            try
            {
                result = await App.AuthenticationClient
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new KasperStart(result));
            }
            catch (MsalClientException)
            {
                
                var a = "aa"; // <- called after succesfull login
            }
        }
```

2: This part in AppDelegate.cs is never called:

```
        public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
        {
            AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
            return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
        }
```

Any idea why?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE 1:**
The MsalClientException-object looks like this:

[image: MsalClientException-object]

And the application output has this error:

```
2021-09-02 11:23:12.987095+0200 Tamago.iOS[44118:4635611] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have now tried for hours, but no matter what I do I get: `The keychain access group xxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache is not enabled in the Entitlements.plist`.

My Entitlements.plist contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>xxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Entitlements.plist is enabled in the iOS Bundle Signing.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: "This part ends in the catch block but I cannot figure out why." - it's because of an `MsalClientException`.  Instead of catching it and **doing nothing** look at the exception details (in the debugger, or log it to the console, etc) to see that it tells you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have updated my question - but I still cannot figure out why these errors occur...

Comment: what does the `Message` property show?  `MsalClientException` generally includes a very clear error message about what generated the exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where do I find the message property?

Comment: it's a property of the Exception object.  Or just try calling `ToString()` on it

Comment: If I do: `var a = MsalClientException.ToString();` I only get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MsalException.ToString()`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Now I get: `ErrorCode: missing_entitlements Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: The application does not have keychain access groups enabled in the Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to …` - now I have something to look for...

Comment: anything to update?

Comment: Yes, just updated. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/783

Comment: Thanks, but nothing seems to solve my problem. However, is the AppIdentifierPrefix always the TeamID? It does not seem to be in my case. For me it is resolved as hbook and not what is stated in Apple Developer as TeamID. Where is the AppIdentifierPrefix defined?

Comment: I do not really know why, but made a few changes to the Info.plist and now it works... Thank you very much.

Comment: @KasperSommer can you please update what are the changes you made in your info.plist that make it works to help other community member as well.

Comment: It might be fixed by changing iphone simulator